# Añadir ID a una fila de una tabla dinámicamente

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, html-tabla

he creado una tabla cuyas filas están determinadas por una llamada a un servicio REST.

Me gustaría añadir un ID de manera dinámica a una de sus columnas en cada fila.

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">  
                <thead>
                    <th>CocheID</th>
                    <th>Puertas</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let coche of coches">
                        <td>{{coche.cocheID}}</td>
                        <td>{{coche.puerta}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>    
            </table>
```

Es decir, me gustaría que cada uno de los cocheID tuviera su ID en el HTML (para así poder llamarlo desde el javascript/typescript). Algo así como fila1, fila2, fila3 ... dependiendo del número de filas creadas.

Un saludo

Comment: No te sirve `<td id="{{coche.cocheID}}">`?

Comment: Luego voy a querer acceder a las filas a través de un for, así que me gustaría que el ID fuera sólo 1,2,3 para  recorrerlo fácilmenete

Comment: Ten en cuenta que puedes recorrer todas las filas aun sin saber su `ID` con `$('#tblOne > tbody  > tr').each(function() {...code...});` por ejemplo.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es añadir a la tabla un <td ><input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxReceiver2"></td> y según cual esté marcado, recoger sus valores o no (el añadir el checkbox sé hacerlo, pero no se cómo recorrerlos luego ya que el número de filas dependerá del servicio rest)

Answer (score 2):

Viendo lo que necesitas puedes simplemente no asignar ningún ID específico a cada fila.

Suponiendo el siguiente código:

Cuando quieras recorrer las filas utiliza:

```js
 $('#tblOne > tbody > tr').each(function() {
      //Comprobaciones por cada fila
      $this = $(this);
      var estado = $this.find('.seleccion').prop('checked');
      console.log(estado);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tblOne">
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="seleccion" checked>I have a bike<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>B</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="seleccion">I have a bike<br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Dentro de cada registro del `.each` puedes hacer las consultas que necesites oportunas. De este modo no necesitas preocuparte del número de registros que obtienes.

`$this.find()` sólo busca dentro del registro actual, por lo que no importa que haya varios con el mismo `class="seleccion"`. Y con `prop('checked')` miramos el estado del checkbox. True = seleccionado y false = No seleccionado.

Comment: Gracias, pero una vez dentro de la fila, como podría saber si el checkbox está marcado? Me refiero, el checkbox tampoco tiene un ID predefinido, así que no tengo muy claro como acceder a él

Comment: Actualizo respuesta @MarioLópezBatres

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas añadir el índice a cada una de las filas, pudiendolo hacer de la siguiente manera en Angular:

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">  
            <thead>
                <th>CocheID</th>
                <th>Puertas</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let coche of coches; index as i">
                    <td>{{i}}</td>
                    <td>{{coche.cocheID}}</td>
                    <td>{{coche.puerta}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
```

En caso de querer conocer que items del array están chequeados a través de angular, podrías asignar el valor checked con un two way binding a una propiedad del coche que sea boolean, como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">  
            <thead>
                <th>CocheID</th>
                <th>Puertas</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let coche of coches; index as i">
                    <td>{{i}}</td>
                    <td>{{coche.cocheID}}</td>
                    <td>{{coche.puerta}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" [checked]="coche.selected"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
```

Pudiendo luego filtrar los coches seleccionados desde un método a través de

```
coches.filter((item) => item.selected);
```